# Applying function "as an afterthought" with arguments

Tags: functions

I want to select all the words from a dictionary which matches a pattern and then filter further with another pattern

> a = "[^awe]"

> Select[DictionaryLookup[   RegularExpression[StringJoin[a, a, "o", a,
> a]]],   StringContainsQ[#, "k"] &]

This works but I like to use the "Select" method "as an afterthought" since it feels natural to read. I tried the following but it throws an error

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin[a, a, "o", a, a]]] // 
 Select[#, StringContainsQ[#1, "k"] &]
```

[image]

What is the error in the above code?

Comment: DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin[a, a, "o", a, a]]] // 
 Function[x, Select[x, StringContainsQ[#, "k"] &]]

Comment: The OP example is just missing the `&` on the end of the outer function... voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example is just missing the `&` on the end of the outer function:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin[a, a, "o", a, a]]] // 
 Select[#, StringContainsQ[#, "k"] &] &
```

Alternatively, both `Select` and `StringContainsQ` offer operator forms:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin[a, a, "o", a, a]]] // 
 Select[StringContainsQ["k"]]
```